# Text box value instant show calling method

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql, ajax

**Script**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function KeyHandler() {
          var result = document.getElementById('result');
        result.innerHTML=document.getElementById('txtInput').value;

    }
 </script>
```

**HTML**

```
       <input type="text" id="inputField" />
       <div id="screen"></div>
```

This code work good in html but i want

```
<a href="#?call=limit.lim&amp;height=400&amp;width=400&amp;id={$ID}&amp;team=

{$Name}&amp;val={'**********'}&amp;name={$Name2}&amp;catname={$Cat}" 

class="inlinePopup" title="{'Namer'}">{$Single}</a>
```

val={'**********'} What ever i type in the text box that's i want here in the star position how

```
 val={'<div id="screen"></div>'} this not work
```

Example : type a value 123 in the text box means that's instant like

```
val = 123
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the `href` attribute of the link in your KeyHandler function.

For example:

```
function keyHandler(){
    var inputText = document.getElementById('inputField').value;
    document.getElementById('myLink').href = '#?yourParam=something&amp;val='+encodeURIComponent(inputText);
}
```

Would work with the HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="inputField" onkeydown="keyHandler()" />
<a href="#" id="myLink">Link Text</a>
```

Could you adapt this technique to suit your needs?  Alternatively, could you provide more details about your problem? Example code, motivation, context etc?